# Add observer to runloop creates retain cycle

Tags: ios, nsrunloop, retain-cycle

```
let observer = CFRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFRunLoopActivity.BeforeWaiting.rawValue, false, 0, { (observer, activity) in

        self.doSomething()

    })

    CFRunLoopAddObserver(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), observer, UITrackingRunLoopMode)
```

I add an observer to main runloop in a UIViewController which means self is an instance of UIViewController. The code above create a retain cycle which lead to the controller will never be released.

I know that I can declare [weak self] or [unowned self] for the block to solve the problem. I want to ask what is exactly the retian cycle look like? I only konw that the block captures self with a strong reference.

Answer (score 3):

If you run this in “Debug Memory Graph” with “Malloc Stack” feature turned on (and “Malloc Scribble” to reduce false positives), you will see that your observer’s closure is likely keeping a strong reference to your view controller:

[image: memory graph]

And because we turned on “Malloc Stack” feature, you can click on the stack on the right and it will take you directly to the code where that strong reference was established. (Needless to say, when you are done debugging, turn off “Malloc Stack”.)

As a general rule, when you have a closure that references `self`, you will want to use `[weak self]` pattern:

```swift
let observer = CFRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFRunLoopActivity.beforeWaiting.rawValue, false, 0) { [weak self] observer, activity in
    self?.doSomething()
}
```

That breaks the strong reference that the run loop’s observer would be maintaining to your view controller. Then, again, if your observer could still be present by the time the view controller is dismissed, you will likely want to remember to `CFRunLoopRemoveObserver` when the view controller is dismissed.

All of this having been said, if your observer is not repeating and you are not keeping a reference to it, generally this closure would be deallocated on its own and your strong reference to the view controller would have been automatically resolved. But the details here are less important than the general observation that the “debug memory graph” tool will help find the strong references, wherever they may be.

For more information, see WWDC 2016 [Visual Debugging with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/410/?time=1466), starting about 24 minutes into that video, will show you how to diagnose these sorts of issues.

Answer (score 1):

There is no retain cycle in the code in your question.

- The run loop retains the observer.
- The observer retains the block.
- The block retains `self`.

That is not a retain cycle.

However, if you store `observer` in a `strong` instance variable, then you have a retain cycle:

- `self` retains the observer.
- The observer retains the block.
- The block retains `self`.

Comment: I am sure I did not store observer in a strong instance variable. If I do not declare self as weak self to be in the block, it will never be released,

Comment: Are you ever removing the observer from the run loop? If you don't remove the observer from the run loop, then the observer will never be deallocated. If the observer is never deallocated, the block will never be deallocated. If the block is never deallocated, the view controller will never be deallocated. This does not mean there's a retain cycle!